# How do I convert a multipage pdf into a multipage png?

Tags: python

When I run the following code, I only get the first file in the list pages in the out.png when I want all of the png files in the list pages to be in out.png.

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

def convert_to_png(input_document):
   pages=convert_from_path(r"C:\Users\jakeh\Downloads"'\\'+input_document+".pdf",poppler_path=r"C:\Users\jakeh\poppler-0.68.0_x86\poppler-0.68.0\bin")

   pages[0].save("out.png",save_all=True,append_images=pages[1:])
```

Comment: PNG format cannot store multiple pages as such. It can store a tall or wide image with all the pages concatenated but that'll be hard to use. TIFF can store multiple pages. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am using amazon textract to extract handwritten data in tables, but it needs to read a PNG or I think it works with JPEG. Can a JPEG have multiple pages?

Comment: Actually, there is an animated PNG format that could store a multi-page document - but support for this variant is not universal.  What program are you using to view the output?

Comment: @jasonharper I need png to be viewed by amazon extract to extract table data.

Comment: A quick look at the Amazon Textract documentation indicates that the only file formats for which it supports multi-page documents are PDF and TIFF.  If you *must* use PNG, then you'd have to save the pages as individual images - but why are you converting the file at all when the original PDF is a supported input format?

Comment: @jasonharper I find Textract to be a lot more effective and accurate when using a PNG or JPeg vs a PDF

Answer (score 1):

You can use pypdfium2 and PIL to combine the pdf pages vertically into one image.

```
import pypdfium2 as pdfium
from PIL import Image

def combine_pdf_pages(pdf_file):
    #Open pdf and extract pages as PIL images
    pdf = pdfium.PdfDocument(pdf_file)
    pages = [pdf.get_page(i) for i in range(len(pdf))]
    pages_as_image = [page.render_to(pdfium.BitmapConv.pil_image) for page in pages]
    
    #Get output image size
    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in pages_as_image))
    total_height = sum(heights)
    max_width = max(widths)
    combined_image = Image.new('RGB', (max_width, total_height))
    y_offset = 0
    
    #Create new img pasting pdf pages
    for im in pages_as_image:
        combined_image.paste(im, (0, y_offset))
        y_offset += im.size[1]
    return combined_image
```

Other option to preserve image quality using `pdf2image`:

Installation:

```
apt-get install poppler-utils
pip install Pillow
pip install pdf2img
```

Convertion code:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
from PIL import Image

def combine_pdf_pages(pdf_file):
    images = convert_from_path(pdf_file,dpi=500)
    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))
    total_height = sum(heights)
    max_width = max(widths)
    combined_image = Image.new('RGB', (max_width, total_height))
    y_offset = 0
    for im in images:
        combined_image.paste(im, (0, y_offset))
        y_offset += im.size[1]
    return combined_image
```

NOTE: The higher the DPI, the better image quality (also increase img size), the lower the DPI, the more pixelated and blurry the image will be.

Usage example:

```
output_img = combine_pdf_pages("your_pdf_path")
output_img.save("your_output_path")
```

Comment: Is there a way to improve the image quality? It works perfectly converting to PNG but in low quality. I think the way to solve it is in its dimensions

Comment: I've added to the original answer a solution to maintain image quality. @Diroallu

Answer (score 0):

I would update that very old poppler *C:\Users...\poppler-0.68.0_x86\poppler-0.68.0\bin* to a more recent like last months 23-01 x64 version. https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows/releases/tag/v23.01.0-0

However much simpler I would use a dragon drop file to run the conversion say this one which (if not used before will download pdftopng) and on subsequent runs not need to download, but you can do similar with latest poppler

**PDF2PNG.bat** (change path to \xpdf\ if you wish and on this years soon update just change 4.04 to 4.05 to update) Save the file and drop a pdf on it, job done.

```
@echo off&Title=PDF2PNG&color 9F&mode con cols=58 lines=7
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "version=xpdf-tools-win-4.04"
set "bin=C:\Apps\PDF\xpdf\%version%\bin32"
if not exist "%bin%\pdftopng.exe" goto download
echo  Enter desired DPi e.g. 200 you can also add one or more
echo  of -alpha/-gray/-mono, and -rot e.g 300 -alpha -rot 270
echo  to specify range add -f # and -l #  e.g. 200 -f 6 -l 10
echo/
set /p "res=? How many DPI ? "
echo processing&"%bin%\pdftopng" -r %res% "%~dpn1.pdf" "%~dpn1-Page"
rem 2>nul
echo processing done
pause
exit /b

:download
mode con cols=82 lines=20&echo/
echo Downloading %version%.zip please wait for full 100%&echo/
MD "%bin%"&cd /d "%bin%\..\.."
curl -O https://dl.xpdfreader.com/%version%.zip
tar -mxf %version%.zip
pause
goto :eof
```

You could remove the download section and addapt output to a fixed resolution say `300 dpi -gray` and also try out the `-aa yes` options for anti alias text.

`200 -gray` should in many cases be good enough for OCR use 300 for smaller text

[image]